# Installed Windows XP as a dual-boot partition with Windows 7. No drivers will install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, troubleshooting

I had Windows 7 and have just created a Windows XP partition.  My computer is an HP Pavillion dv6000.  Now, none of the drivers provided on the hp site will install.  The only driver of particular interest to me is my wireless network adapter, but what gives!  Does it have something to do with it being the F drive, rather than the C drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it should not make a difference what so ever (unless they use a custom, very bad installer). Try re-downloading the driver and remember that the Windows 7 and XP drivers will be different.

If you have a problem, try looking up who actually makes the device ([Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com), [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) etc.) and go to their site directly and download the latest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dual booting or have you actually installed two windows systems on two seperate drives in the same machine?

Dual booting would produce no problems because both systems would then see their own 'c:\' drive and have seperate drivers for sound, video, networking, etc.

If you have actually installed the sytems on two drives and try to run them seperatly, each system will find the other's drivers and you will have different conflicts for video, sound, networking, etc.

Check your operating system setup and confirm what you've got and how you're going about it.

Good luck, and hope this helps you.